# Caching issue in frameset frame

Tags: caching, web-applications, frameset

I have a web application and it is done in VS 2003[C#].

There is a frameset which is divided into 3.

1. TopFrame
2. LeftFrame
3. ContentFrame

LeftFrame loads contents related to each logged in user. The contents are loaded from SQL Server 2000 database.

But there occurs a strange problem when one user logs out and another logs in. The leftframe for the first user is shown to the new user logged in. The code executes normally but the content is not shown properly.

I think this is a caching issue. Right now we have disabled the caching of each page by setting

```
HttpCacheability.NoCache
```

But this makes the page loading slower. Is there any alternative way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this article will help you.
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030528.htm

> **SUMMARY** : Any developer who has had the dubious task of developing a
>   Web site utilizing frames knows it can
>   be an uphill battle. 
>   1. Frames are Evil
>   2. The Devil created Frames
>   3. If you are having a problem related to the Target, refer to item 1
>   4. If you are trying to refresh data in a particular frame, refer to 1

Comment: Is there a replacement for frameset in VS 2003?

Comment: There isn't a real replacement for frames by some sort of control. Currently div and span tags, together with CSS, are used to layout modern sites/webapplications.

http://www.google.be/search?hl=en&q=using+div+and+css+to+layout&meta

Comment: But I have to use frames because most of the time only the content page will be reloaded.

Comment: And to avoid repetitive designs for pages.